# Adding shaded target region to ggplot2 barchart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two data frames: one I am using to create the bars in a barchart and a second that I am using to create a shaded "target region" behind the bars using geom_rect.

Here is example data:

```
test.data <- data.frame(crop=c("A","B","C"), mean=c(6,4,12))
target.data <-  data.frame(crop=c("ONE","TWO"), mean=c(31,12), min=c(24,9), max=c(36,14))
```

I start with the means of test.data for the bars and means of target.data for the line in the target region:

```
library(ggplot2)
a <- ggplot(test.data, aes(y=mean, x=crop)) + geom_hline(aes(yintercept = mean, color = crop), target.data) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
a
```

[image]

So far so good, but then when I try to add a shaded region to display the min-max range of target.data, there is an issue. The shaded region appears just fine, but somehow, the crops from target.data are getting added to the x-axis. I'm not sure why this is happening.

```
b <- a + geom_rect(aes(xmin=-Inf, xmax=Inf, ymin=min, ymax=max, fill = crop), data = target.data, alpha = 0.5)
b
```

[image]

How can I add the geom_rect shapes without adding those extra names to the x-axis of the bar-chart?

Comment: What are you trying to visualize with this plot overall and specifically geom_rect()?

Comment: It's because your `x` variable is named crop but in your second dataset it has different values.  Adding `inherit.aes = FALSE` to `geom_rect` should fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution to your question, but I'd like to better understand you problem because we might be able to make a more interpretable plot. All you have to do is add aes(x = NULL) to your geom_rect() call. I took the liberty to change the variable 'crop' in add.data to 'brop' to minimize any confusion.

```
test.data <- data.frame(crop=c("A","B","C"), mean=c(6,4,12))
add.data <-  data.frame(brop=c("ONE","TWO"), mean=c(31,12), min=c(24,9), max=c(36,14))

ggplot(test.data, aes(y=mean, x=crop)) +
  geom_hline(data = add.data, aes(yintercept = mean, color = brop)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  geom_rect(data = add.data, aes(xmin=-Inf, xmax=Inf, x = NULL, ymin=min, ymax=max, fill = brop),
    alpha = 0.5, show.legend = F)
```

In ggplot calls all of the aesthetics or aes() are inherited from the intial call:

ggplot(data, aes(x=foo, y=bar)).

That means that regardless of what layers I add on geom_rect(), geom_hline(), etc. ggplot is looking for 'foo' to assign to x and 'bar' to assign to y, unless you specifically tell it otherwise. So like aeosmith pointed out you can clear all inherited aethesitcs for a layer with inherit.aes = FALSE, or you can knock out single variables at a time by reassigning them as NULL.

Comment: Maybe add an explanation of why this was happening?  Another alternative is to use `inherit.aes = FALSE` in `geom_rect` so global aesthetics aren't inherited.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Makes sense...I'm just new to ggplot2 and coming from lattice. Yes, the example shown is quite ugly, but it's just an example...my real application is more interpretable.